# Default behaviour for accessing facebook apps via mobile

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'm developing a HTML5 canvas app to sit on facebook. I need to ensure the app also works on mobile phones. What I'm struggling to work out is:

if a user finds the app via the native facebook app on their ios/android/wp, does the app get shown within the facebook native app like on iOS or does it always jump off to the web browser to the mobile version of facebook like most phones?

Any help or advice much appreciated

Shaun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the iOS facebook app displays any website links within the app. Android and wp8 jump to the browser.